# Custom Validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am having two textboxes and a submit button. I have applied Custom validation to the First TextBox. When i am loosing my focus from the first textbox, Custom validator is doing validation.But i want that validation on Button Click only.

Comment: post your .aspx code so we can see where the problem is

Comment: This is generally how a custom validator will behave.  Why *DON'T* you want the validation to happen when the box loses focus?

Comment: Because i want a summary report during page submission.

Answer (score 1):

Validate using javascript...
on button click call javascript method, where you can check textbox value and prompt message.

Comment: I am using Validator callout Extender. Can i use javascript function to show message in callout extender.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did your custom validation at page load method. I don't know where you want validation at client side or at server.

1. You can use validation control / javascript for client side validation
2. For server side you can write code of validation at button click.